# Executar PHP de forma ordenada

Tags: php, ssh

Tenho um arquivo `.php` onde me conecto via SSH em um servidor, e executo comandos atráves dele. Meu arquivo é basicamente isso:

```
$conexao(servidor,usuario,senha,PORTA);

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 1');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 1';

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 2');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 2';

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 3');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 3';
```

Ele executa normalmente os comandos, sem erros, porém o PHP executa todos os comandos, e só depois disso mostra a saída dos comandos `echo`, todos de uma só vez.

Eu queria que ao executar o `COMANDO1`, fosse mostrado logo abaixo a saída do `echo`, informando que o comando deu certo, e depois partir para o próximo comando e assim por diante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP até imprime em ordem, o problema é que geralmente o seu navegador vai fazer caching da resposta, para só mostrar para o usuário a resposta depois de recebe-la por completo.

Você pode adicionar alguns `headers` na resposta do servidor, para servir como metadados, de forma a informar ao navegador que ele deve exibir qualquer que seja o resultado assim que recebe-lo.

Para isso geralmente esses dois headers são utilizados:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
```

Eles irão informar ao seu navegador tanto que a sua resposta é um stream, e que não é para fazer o caching da resposta. Detalhe que esse stream é apenas um texto, se você for enviar um HTML, seu navegador não irá fazer parse desse HTML automaticamente (até porque não tem como fazer o parse de um HTML incompleto).

O seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 1');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 1';
flush(); // para imprimir todo o cache do stdout

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 2');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 2';
flush();

$ssh->exec('COMANDO 3');
echo'SUCESSO AO EXECUTAR COMANDO 3';
flush();
```

Comment: No exemplo citei o echo como echo 'Sucesso'; só que o meu echo de verdade é echo '<span class="txtsucesso">Sucesso</span>'; um span com um style, pra ficar mais bonito o texto, teria problema?

Comment: O "problema" é que esse `<span>` não será interpretado como HTML, e sim como um texto qualquer. Se você precisa tratar essa resposta do servidor, vai precisar de um pouco de JavaScript, como por exemplo utilizar `EventSource`.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não tenho as ferramentas para fazer o teste aqui, mas tente excluir o header `Content-Type: text/event-stream` e verifique se ainda funciona, talvez isso seja o bastante para interpretar a resposta como um HTML. Não tenho como garantir que irá funcionar.

Comment: @Paulo, o PHP envia conforme você faz o `echo`, é o navegador que faz caching para exibir só no final. Como você está fazendo essa requisição? Você está utilizando um redirecionamento simples, ou utilizando AJAX?

Comment: Consegui fazer os echos apareçerem em ordem, porem tive k adcionar um código depois dos headers que é "ob_end_flush();"  o que ele faz?

Comment: E sim, removendo "header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');" consigo usar elementos html no echo tranquilamente